EPPlus C# как скопировать готовый шаблон, созданный в ручную, из одного файла Excel в другой
подскажите пожалуйста, как можно скопировать шаблон диаграммы (название, настройку осей и настройку легенды) из одного файла Excel в другой. Перепробовал кучу методов, но самый лучший результат это просто копирование пустой диаграммы. С# библиотека EPPlus
